# Extracting xml tages from xml file through unix script/command

Tags: shell, unix

This is my sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <testjar>
 <testable>
  <trigger>Trigger1</trigger>
  <message->2012-06-14T00:03.54</message>
 <sales-info>
  <san-a>no</san-a>
  <san-b>no</san-b>
  <san-c>no</san-c>
  </sales-info>
  </testable>
  </testjar>
```

I need to extract xml tags from this-

e.g. output of above file should be

```
testjar
testable
trigger
message
sales-info
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$> cat ./text
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <testjar>
 <testable>
  <trigger>Trigger1</trigger>
  <message>2012-06-14T00:03.54</message>
 <sales-info>
  <san-a>no</san-a>
  <san-b>no</san-b>
  <san-c>no</san-c>
  </sales-info>
  </testable>
  </testjar>
```

And

```
$> grep -P -o "(?<=\<)[^>?/]*(?=\>)" ./text
testjar
testable
trigger
message
sales-info
san-a
san-b
san-c
```

Regular expression `(?<=\<)[^>?/]*(?=\>)` consist of 3 parts:

- `(?<=\<)`: `(?<=)` is lookbehind operator, so it means "after <";
- `[^>?/]*`: not `>`,`?`,`/` 0 or more times;
- `(?=\>)`: `(?=)` is lookahead operator, so it means "before >"

Comment: Can you explain what does '>' on the start of the command? I.e. $> cat . Пожалуйста. And why you use ./ which means an execution, afaik.

Comment: `$>` is my bash PS1. It indicates that following line is shell query. `./` means "current directory" ⇒ `./text` ≡ `text`.

Comment: I have checked if file comes in single line also, it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F">" '{print $1}' xmlfile | sed -e '/<\//d' -e '/<?/d' -e 's/<//g'
```

Comment: If file comes in single line then its not providing any output.